# How to add images when creating Visual C++ MFC project from scratch?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I am try to create very simple c++ MFC project. Since it is very simple one I need to create it form scratch.

my code so far is shown below. But now I need to add picture control and thus my Intent use CImage class. But to use CImage class I need to add altimage.h header to my project. But When I do so it gives a error that cannot open source file altimage.h. So

1. How can I overcome this problem.
2. How to add the file I needed when I creating the MFC projects form the scratch.

please help me solvethis.

thanks

```
#include <afxwin.h>      //MFC core and standard components
//#include <altimage>
#include "resource.h"    //main symbols

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Globals
//CEdit * TEST;

CEdit * RECOG_CHARS;
CButton * BTN_CONVERT;
CButton  * BTN_QUIT;
CStatic * IMG_IMAGE;

class HWCR_FORM : public CDialog
{
public:
    HWCR_FORM(CWnd* pParent = NULL) : CDialog(HWCR_FORM::IDD, pParent)
    {    }

    // Dialog Data, name of dialog form
    enum{ IDD = ID_MAIN_INTERFACE };


protected:

    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) { CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX); }
    //Called right after constructor. Initialize things here.

    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog()
    {
        CDialog::OnInitDialog();

        RECOG_CHARS = (CEdit *)GetDlgItem(CE_ID_TEXT);
        BTN_CONVERT = (CButton *)GetDlgItem(CB_ID_START);
        BTN_QUIT = (CButton *)GetDlgItem(CB_ID_QUIT);
        IMG_IMAGE = (CStatic *)GetDlgItem(CS_ID_IMAGE);

        HBITMAP image = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,L"C:\\Users\\Kasun\\Desktop\\image.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP,150,120,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        IMG_IMAGE->SetBitmap(image);



        RECOG_CHARS->SetWindowTextW(L"Hi there");


        return true;
    }

public:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class HWCR : public CWinApp
{

public:
    HWCR() {  }

public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CWinApp::InitInstance();
        SetRegistryKey(_T("Hills Of Darkness"));


        HWCR_FORM dlg;
        m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
        INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();



        return FALSE;
    } //close function

};


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Need a Message Map Macro for both CDialog and CWinApp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(HWCR_FORM, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

HWCR theApp;
```

Answer (score 2):

First at all, in order to use `CImage`, you need to include header file

```
#include <atlimage.h>
```

instead of

```
#include <altimage>
```

Secondly, be sure that this file's directory is included into MSVC paths...
Normally it should be included as this header file is part of MFC / Win32 SDK....check the directories in VS properties.

Z.

Comment: I have change the first one you have mention, For second What field I should check in the properties. Can you please tell me the exact steps to follow. It would be grate help. thanks

Comment: So you put <atlimage.h> and it still fails ?
If so, please verify that the file atlimage.h does exist on your system. Have a look in the directory where your Visual C++ is installed.

Comment: Yes when I add that, it underlines the #include in red as in the error, when I locate my cursor to that it says cannot open source file.

Comment: which properties should I check to find out wether these header are added or not

Comment: Note: These ATL header files are not part of Visual Studio Express. Is that what you installed ?

Comment: I have VS ultimate..Note I have create the empty project and included file later. So is this cause of not adding the include libraries or some thing.

Comment: OK. I think I found out the problem. 
On my system, I had download and installed the SDK manually months ago.
But in the latest Microsoft SDKs, those ATL stuff might not be included by default.  Have a look in Microsoft SDK website. 
It makes sense as ATL became a bit obsolete though.